# Не могу убрать черный фон с мапы

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Не могу убрать черный фон с мапы. Пробывал в настройках увеличить поле, но не помогает(крысным я показал)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: O_o unreal engine 4 .....а на каком языке пишите можно спросить ?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов С++